# Group multiple rows with different column values to a single row

Tags: database-design, teradata

I have 3 records with 3 column values for the same key.
PFB sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    student varchar(100),
    maths int,
    physics int,
    chemistry int
)
PRIMARY INDEX (student)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO student('Student_100', 90,   ,   );
INSERT INTO student('Student_100',   , 80,   );
INSERT INTO student('Student_100',   ,   , 70);
```

Now, for student_100, there are 3 records with 3 column values. 
I want to get output like below

```
StudentID   | Maths | Physics | Chemistry
------------+-------+---------+----------
Student_100 |  90   |   80    |    70
```

A single record with all column values. I don't want to use SUM function, because I have columns with Date type as well. So I am looking for a solution that fits all datatypes.

Comment: Please specify what DBMS you're using, so we can try to make sure we give you SQL that would work there.

Comment: First - your second insert would fail, since `student` is a primary key. You can't have multiple rows with the same primary key. So, with that table structure, the second and third `INSERT`s would have to be `UPDATE`s - which removes your problem, since the values are already there. Please update your question to clarify just how this is intended to work, as it doesn't make much sense right now. If there are other tables involved, please include their descriptions as well.

Comment: Model is wrong, thats the problem.

Comment: I am using, teradata. Student is just a primary index, not unique in this case. This is just a sample structure.

Comment: Tag it then (https://pastebin.com/hzagzNDe)

Comment: Simply use `MAX` instead of `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the desired result GROUPING BY student and getting max value of each subject.

You can find some examples of MAX function on TERADATA [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_aggregate_functions.htm) or [here](http://forgetcode.com/Teradata/1655-MAX).

```
SELECT   student as StudentID,
         MAX(maths) as Maths,
         MAX(physics) as Physics,
         MAX(chemistry) as Chemistry
FROM     student
GROUP BY student;
```